# Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: column reference "....." is ambiguous

Tags: sql, postgresql

i tried query in mytable like this..

```
select count(*) as jml from 
                news n 
                join ref_news_category c on n.id_category=c.id_category 
                join ref_user u on n.who_post=u.uid 
                 where n.type in ('member','public')
            order by 
                last_update desc
```

but i get this error, 
`Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: column reference "last_update" is ambiguous LINE 7: last_update desc`
what wrong in myquery?
helpme please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`last_update` must be a column name in more than one of the tables in your query, so you need to specify the exact instance of that column you want to use in the `order by`.

e.g. say the `news` table has that column, you would say `order by n.last_update`.

Comment: yes i try that to, but error `Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: column "n.last_update" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate`

Comment: Why do you use ORDER BY when you get only one result? There is no order in a single result. And if you do need the last_update field, you must add it to a GROUP BY and mention it in your SELECT statement.

Comment: because i want the output is descending

Comment: your query returns just one record. What's the difference between ascending and descending on a single record?